# Scala REPL exiting automatically

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

Scala REPL is behaving oddly or perhaps this is the expected behavior. When I create a MainFrame object and set its visibility true, a window is displayed. However, If I close the window the Scala REPL exits to the terminal. Sample session:

```
 ~$ scala
 scala> import swing._
 scala> val frame = new MainFrame()
 scala> frame.visible = true
 ~$                             //when I close the window
```

I am using scala 2.9.1 on kubuntu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the `MainFrame` class itself, coupled with the not-very-OO behaviour of `System.exit`.

This is the entire source of `MainFrame`:

```
class MainFrame extends Frame {
  override def closeOperation() { sys.exit(0) }
}
```

Looking at that, it's pretty clear that when the window is closed, `System.exit` is called and the JVM will quit.

If you were just experimenting when you found this, the workaround is to just not do this!  If you want to use a frame in the REPL, then you can either override `closeOperation` to not exit the JVM - or just use a `Frame` (since the only additional functionality with MainFrame is the JVM exit behaviour).

Answer (score 7):

As it says in [the documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/swing/MainFrame.html):

> *Shuts down the framework and quits the application when closed.*

(I.e., it shuts down the JVM which the REPL runs in.)

To prevent this behavior you could either simply use a `Frame` instead, or override the `closeOperation` method.

Here is the [source for `MainFrame.scala`](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//swing/scala/swing/MainFrame.scala#L1) for reference:

```
/**
 * A frame that can be used for main application windows. Shuts down the
 * framework and quits the application when closed.
 */
class MainFrame extends Frame {
  override def closeOperation() { sys.exit(0) }
}
```